# Freemarker: Accessing elements in a list, which is in a list

Tags: java, markdown, freemarker

I currently have following structure:

```
List<List<ClusterEntry>> clusters = new ArrayList<List<ClusterEntry>>();
//fill clusters and the list in clusters
input.put("clusters", clusters);
```

clusters describes my clusters and cluster.get(i) contains all the elements in one cluster.
For a report I want to output this result with freemarker into a .md file
The goal is to have as much columns as clusters and in each row an entry of the corresponding cluster.
This is my .ftl code:

```
<#list clusters as c> | Cluster ${c_index} |
<#list c[c_index] as entry> | ${entry.name} | </#list>
</#list>
```

however, this results into the following error

```
The value you try to list is an extended_hash+string (package.ClusterEntry wrapped into f.e.b.StringModel), thus you must specify two loop variables after the "as"; one for the key, and another for the value, like <#... as k, v>).
```

How do I access the entry properly? 
And if you already are here reading this, how can I achieve my column row structre properly with this nested loop? Currently I assume this will all be seperate rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `<#list c[c_index] as entry>` write `<#list c as entry>`, because `c` already holds the current list item from `clusters`.

As of generating a nice markdown table, it's rather tricky, as you had to know the length of the longest nested `List<ClusterEntry>` before starting rendering anything. Also if it has to look good on source level, you had to figure out the maximum width of each column too. Calculating such things in the template won't be nice... perhaps you should do that in Java and pass the information to the template in the data-model.

Comment: First: Thank you, that helped perfectly. Second: I already have done the information calculation. I did this with java before, meaning writing a .csv file. For this I had the longest row number calculated. How would I then go with this for the nice Style? And is there no way going with the double nesting to fill out the rows and columns? And if I do not have an entry in the list I could leave it empty?

Comment: Not sure where exactly do you have difficulties, but to pad rows to the desired length you might want to use something like `<#list c?chunk(numberOfColumns, '')>` (see http://freemarker.org/docs/ref_builtins_sequence.html#ref_builtin_chunk).

Comment: I think I will add this as a seperate question to make my current issue clear. Thank you for you help again on the first problem!